# DDClient with OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, dynamic-dns, dynamic-ip, ufw

I'm at a complete loss trying to figure out how to obtain my local public IP address, rather than my VPN's public IP address as my VPN doesn't seem to  allow incoming traffic. Basically, I need ddclient to bypass OpenVPN when getting my public IP.

I've been using UFW to send traffic to OpenVPN and have a few openings for my backup service and local network connections. How would I open it for ddclient?

Comment: This is a routing problem.  Without details about your VPN configuration, and route setup, it is hard to give any specific suggestions.

Comment: What do you need? I'm happy to update with any output